# JSF Datatable updates only once during session

Tags: jsf, primefaces, datatable

So, I am loading a list from H2 database to be shown, and it is updated with data from form on previous page. The datatable is update only once in session, after I submit form first time. If I reset tomcat server, all the data submitted in last session will be shown. I will upload all the code that I consider relevant,:

Managed bean, with the TaskList datatable:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class TaskListController {
private List<Task> taskList;
private Task task;

@PostConstruct
private void init() {
    taskList = TaskServiceDatabase.taskList();
}

public String loadFirstPage() {

    return "createNewTask.xhtml";
}

public List<Task> getTaskList() {
    return taskList;
}

//getters and setters
```

Tasklist method:

```
public static List<Task> taskList() {

    List<Task> taskList = new ArrayList<Task>();

    try {
        taskList = DatabaseUtils.fetchTask();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return taskList;
}
```

Fetch task method is communicating with database, I am fairly certain this works properly, if it is needed, I can add it.

And here is the.xhtml file:

```
    <h:form id="form">
    <p:dataTable id="taskTable" var="task" rowIndexVar="taskNumber"
        value="#{taskListController.taskList}" paginator="true" rows="10"
        paginatorTemplate="{CurrentPageReport} {FirstPageLink} {PreviousPageLink} {PageLinks} {NextPageLink} {LastPageLink} {RowsPerPageDropdown}"
        rowsPerPageTemplate="5,10,15">
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Surname" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{task.user.surname}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Name" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{task.user.name}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Username" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{task.user.username}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Project name" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{task.project.projectName}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Company name" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{task.project.companyName}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Task description" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{task.description}" />
        </p:column>
        <p:column>
            <f:facet name="header">
                <h:outputText value="Time (h)" />
            </f:facet>
            <h:outputText value="#{task.time}" />
        </p:column>

    </p:dataTable>
    <h:commandButton action="#{taskListController.loadFirstPage}"
        value="Return" update="form" />
</h:form>
```

So, what did I do wrong?

Comment: Works as you implemented it. You load it in the postConstuct of a sessionscoped bean so it is only loaded once

Comment: Yeap, after changing scope to ViewScoped, it worked

Answer (score 0):

Changing scope of bean to ViewScoped solved the issue